# UnicodeEncodeError Python in spyder with alive-progress

Tags: python-3.x, progress-bar, spyder, encode

I am using Spyder 4.1.1 from anaconda and Python 3.7.6 in W10. I am using the module alive-progress for one of my projects. Just using basic lines of the following code:

```
from alive_progress import alive_bar
import time


for x in 3000, 4000, 2000, 0:
    with alive_bar(x) as bar:
        for i in range(3000):
            time.sleep(0.002)
            bar(0)
```

I am getting the next error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "\\My_path\alive_bar.py", line 10, in <module>
    bar(0)

  File "C:\Users\delprf2\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 119, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)

  File "C:\Users\delprf2\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\alive_progress\progress.py", line 275, in alive_bar
    alive_repr()

  File "C:\Users\delprf2\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\alive_progress\progress.py", line 118, in alive_repr
    sys.__stdout__.write(line + (spin and '\r' or '\n'))

  File "C:\Users\delprf2\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 1-40: character maps to <undefined>
```

Does anyone how to solve it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of alive-progress!

It seems your system Python or terminal is not accepting Unicode characters. I don't know anaconda, but why is it using `cp1252`? It should accept `utf8` by default.

Anyway, please try with a theme that does not use any fancy chars:

```
from alive_progress import alive_bar
import time


for x in 3000, 4000, 2000, 0:
    with alive_bar(x, theme='classic') as bar:
        for i in range(3000):
            time.sleep(0.002)
            bar()
```

Please find more details at: https://github.com/rsalmei/alive-progress.

And if you have any other doubts, you can always open an issue in there so I can help you.